# Org Agenda is looking for agenda file names inside of my todo file

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-agenda

When I try to open a org-agenda view, I am prompted with emacs claiming that the first line of my todo list is not a valid file, with options to remove it from the agenda list, or abort. Removing it removes the actual line from my .org file.

This is what's in my config:
 (setq org-agenda-files "~/org/todo.org")

Comment: Try making a backup of your todo file, and replace it with the simplest one you can (single TODO headline with a scheduled time).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `org-agenda-files` is either:

- A string naming a directory which contains agenda files
- A string naming a file whose contents list the agenda files (this is the situation you find yrself in).
- A list of file names.

So, to achieve what you want, you need

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/todo.org"))
```